# PHP MySQL Insert Query that won't insert if already exists

Tags: php, mysql, sql, unique, sql-insert

I've been doing some research and haven't found anything that I've been able to make work, unfortunately, and I think that stems from not understanding the MySQL construct in the examples I've been looking at.

What I'm trying to do is run an insert query, and do a check on values in 3 specific columns to ensure they don't exist, then insert, else do nothing.

My Table is pretty basic: id(int11), user(varchar(45)), label(varchar(255)), agent(varchar(255)), empid(varchar(10)).

My id is my Primary, with Auto increment, and here is my code I currently have that works on inserting, but doesn't have the handling in place for duplicates:

```
$i = 0;
foreach ($agents as $ag){
    $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `pms_users` 
    (`id`,`user`,`label`,`agent`,`empid`)
     VALUES 
    (NULL, '$user','$group','$labels[$i]','$ag')");
    $i ++;
}
```

The three columns I need to check against are the $user, $group, and $ag.

Comment: Can't you just run a select query specific to your insert target as a test for insertion?

Comment: You should stop using the `mysql` extension. It has been deprecated for many years, and is totally removed in PHP 7. Switch to `mysqli` or `PDO`, and also learn to use prepared statements to prevent SQL injection.

Comment: Thanks Barmar - I appreciate the example you provided below, in addition you to providing best practices. The Unique Index works just as I need it to. Additionally, I use PDO for other projects, and use prepared statements, but I'm constrained to the mysql version I currently have until we get new hardware, so I'll have to settle for mysql_real_escape to sanitize any free form inputs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can only have one row per combination of user, label and agent, you should define them as a unique constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE pms_users ADD CONSTRAINT pms_users_unq UNIQUE (`user`, `label`, `agent`);
```

And then let the database do the heavy lifting with an insert-ignore statement:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO `pms_users`
(`user`, `label`, `agent`, `empid`)
VALUES ('some_user', 'some_label', 'some_agent', 123)
```

Comment: Thanks Mureinik, I really appreciate the example. I was able to get this to work by adding 'Unique Index' as specified above by Barmar, but can you tell me the difference between Unique Index and Unique Constraint? I'd very much like to learn best practices, in addition to having it work the way it should.

Answer (score 5):

Add a unique index for `(user, label, empid)`. Then the database won't allow you to create duplicates.

```
ALTER TABLE pms_users
ADD UNIQUE INDEX (user, label, empid);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try insert on duplicate key update query.. It checks  duplicate keys. If they exist MySQL do update query if not exist MySQL doing insert query.
Sure in your database you should declare unique keys. 
Here is MySQL documentation for this case
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html